# How to deal with "no set size" arrays in pinvoke structs?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, pinvoke

How would you write this type of struct in c#?

```
struct _JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST {
  DWORD     NumberOfAssignedProcesses;
  DWORD     NumberOfProcessIdsInList;
  ULONG_PTR ProcessIdList[1];
}
```

sins there is no set size for the `ProcessIdList` array, what do you do? Do you just write it like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST
{
   int NumberOfAssignedProcesses;
   int NumberOfProcessIdsInList;
   IntPtr ProcessIdList; //Must point to a allocated array, thanks jdweng for letting me know.
}
```

or do you just assign a size which is big enough, e.g.:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST
{
   int NumberOfAssignedProcesses;
   int NumberOfProcessIdsInList;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
   UIntPtr[] ProcessIdList; //Works just fine, but is limited to the SizeConst.
}
```

Comment: You first approach is correct.  You have a 32 bit pointer.  But the pointer must point to allocated memory that is the size of one ProcesIDList.  And the memory has to be in unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of structure is usually declared (there are others like this one in WLan APIs for example) :

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST
    {
        public int NumberOfAssignedProcesses;
        public int NumberOfProcessIdsInList;
        public IntPtr[] ProcessIdList;
        public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST(IntPtr pList)
        {
            int nIntSize = Marshal.SizeOf<int>(); // 4
            NumberOfAssignedProcesses = Marshal.ReadInt32(pList, 0);
            NumberOfProcessIdsInList = Marshal.ReadInt32(pList, nIntSize);
            ProcessIdList = new IntPtr[NumberOfProcessIdsInList];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfProcessIdsInList; i++)
            {
                IntPtr pItemList = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>() == 4)
                    pItemList = new IntPtr(pList.ToInt32() + (i * Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>()) + (nIntSize * 2));
                else
                    pItemList = new IntPtr(pList.ToInt64() + (i * Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>()) + (nIntSize * 2));
                IntPtr nPID = new IntPtr();
                nPID = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pItemList, 0);
                ProcessIdList[i] = nPID;
            }
        }
    }
```

A test with 5 Notepad launched and assigned to a job with *JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE*,
then **QueryInformationJobObject** to enumerate the PIDs by using this structure =>

```
        private IntPtr hJob = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool bRet = false;
        hJob  = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, "Test Job Object");
        JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jbeli = new JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION();
        jbeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags |= (JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE | JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK | JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK);
        int nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION));
        IntPtr pJobInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(jbeli, pJobInfo, false);           
        SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS.JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, pJobInfo, (uint)nLength);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pJobInfo);

        int nNbProcesses = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < nNbProcesses; i++)
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = new Process())
            {
                exeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
                exeProcess.Start();
                exeProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
                IntPtr hProcess = exeProcess.Handle;
                bRet = AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, hProcess);
            }
        }

        JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST jobpil = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST();
        jobpil.NumberOfAssignedProcesses = nNbProcesses;
        int nSize = Marshal.SizeOf<JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST>() + (nNbProcesses - 1) * Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>();
        IntPtr pJobpil = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(jobpil, pJobpil, false);
        int nReturnLength = 0;
        bRet = QueryInformationJobObject(hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS.JobObjectBasicProcessIdList,  pJobpil, nSize, out nReturnLength);
        if (bRet)
        {
            var processidlist = new JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST(pJobpil);
            foreach (var pid in processidlist.ProcessIdList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PID: {0}", pid.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int nErr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Win32Exception win32Exception = new Win32Exception(nErr);
            this.Activate();
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + win32Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pJobpil);


    // CloseHandle can be added in Form1_FormClosed :

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseHandle(hJob);
    }
```

Declarations =>

```
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateJobObject(IntPtr lpJobAttributes, string lpName);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS JobObjectInfoClass, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, uint cbJobObjectInfoLength);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool AssignProcessToJobObject(IntPtr hJob, IntPtr hProcess);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool QueryInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS JobObjectInformationClass, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] IntPtr lpJobObjectInformation, int cbJobObjectInformationLength, out int lpReturnLength);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            public ulong PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
            public ulong PerJobUserTimeLimit;
            public int LimitFlags;
            public IntPtr MinimumWorkingSetSize;
            public IntPtr MaximumWorkingSetSize;
            public int ActiveProcessLimit;
            public IntPtr Affinity;
            public int PriorityClass;
            public int SchedulingClass;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct IO_COUNTERS
        {
            public ulong ReadOperationCount;
            public ulong WriteOperationCount;
            public ulong OtherOperationCount;
            public ulong ReadTransferCount;
            public ulong WriteTransferCount;
            public ulong OtherTransferCount;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
        {
            public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
            public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
            public IntPtr ProcessMemoryLimit;
            public IntPtr JobMemoryLimit;
            public IntPtr PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
            public IntPtr PeakJobMemoryUsed;
        }

        //
        // Basic Limits
        //
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_WORKINGSET = 0x00000001;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_TIME = 0x00000002;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME = 0x00000004;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_ACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000008;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_AFFINITY = 0x00000010;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PRESERVE_JOB_TIME = 0x00000040;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SCHEDULING_CLASS = 0x00000080;

        //
        // Extended Limits
        //
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY = 0x00000100;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY = 0x00000200;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY_HIGH = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_DIE_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION = 0x00000400;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK = 0x00000800;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK = 0x00001000;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE = 0x00002000;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SUBSET_AFFINITY = 0x00004000;
        public const int JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_MEMORY_LOW = 0x00008000;

        public enum JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS
        {
            JobObjectBasicAccountingInformation = 1,
            JobObjectBasicLimitInformation,
            JobObjectBasicProcessIdList,
            JobObjectBasicUIRestrictions,
            JobObjectSecurityLimitInformation,  // deprecated
            JobObjectEndOfJobTimeInformation,
            JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation,
            JobObjectBasicAndIoAccountingInformation,
            JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation,
            JobObjectJobSetInformation,
            JobObjectGroupInformation,
            JobObjectNotificationLimitInformation,
            JobObjectLimitViolationInformation,
            JobObjectGroupInformationEx,
            JobObjectCpuRateControlInformation,
            JobObjectCompletionFilter,
            JobObjectCompletionCounter,
            JobObjectReserved1Information = 18,
            JobObjectReserved2Information,
            JobObjectReserved3Information,
            JobObjectReserved4Information,
            JobObjectReserved5Information,
            JobObjectReserved6Information,
            JobObjectReserved7Information,
            JobObjectReserved8Information,
            JobObjectReserved9Information,
            JobObjectReserved10Information,
            JobObjectReserved11Information,
            JobObjectReserved12Information,
            JobObjectReserved13Information,
            JobObjectReserved14Information = 31,
            JobObjectNetRateControlInformation,
            JobObjectNotificationLimitInformation2,
            JobObjectLimitViolationInformation2,
            JobObjectCreateSilo,
            JobObjectSiloBasicInformation,
            JobObjectReserved15Information = 37,
            JobObjectReserved16Information,
            JobObjectReserved17Information,
            JobObjectReserved18Information,
            JobObjectReserved19Information = 41,
            JobObjectReserved20Information,
            MaxJobObjectInfoClass
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think any of the ways you mentioned should work.

In addition, there is a matching feature in c#: Define an array with the fixed keyword:

```
struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_PROCESS_ID_LIST
{
   int NumberOfAssignedProcesses;
   int NumberOfProcessIdsInList;
   fixed IntPtr ProcessIdList[1];
}
```

See documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers

Also no bounds check, so you should be able to read behind the end of the struckt easily:

> Note
>
> Except for memory created by using stackalloc, the C# compiler and the common language runtime (CLR) do not perform any security buffer overrun checks. As with all unsafe code, use caution.

Comment: Oh, ok. I knew about fixed size buffers but was told that it's not wise to use em so i kind of stay away from them.
Another question if you wouldn't mind answering, not to different from this one, what do you do with strings where in the struct the fields are layed out as `DWORD StrLength => LPWSTR Str => DWORD Attribute` is it the same thing as with arrays (`IntPtr`/`fixed char[]`)?

Comment: This is incorrect. The point about the array in the unmanaged structure is that it can hold arbitrary length.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You don't have a bounds check for it. This means you can access x.ProcessIdList[2] even when the array size is defined as 1.

Comment: Ask yourself how you declare such a structure with an array whose length is greater than 1. So long as somebody else has declared this, it is fine, just as in C++. But how are you going to declare such a thing in C#. Consider the text of your actual answer, "I think any of the ways you mentioned should work." In fact neither of the two ways suggested in the question can work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I tested all 3 ways and while you are correct about 1 of the ways not working, the first one with `IntPtr ProcessIdList;`, you are incorrect about the second, it works just fine sins it technically does declare `new UIntPtr[MAX_PATH]`, the only downside to this is that if there are more than 260 process ids then obviously you wont be able to access the other ones. The one in this answer doesn't work sins it basically destroys the struct, and you also can't do `fixed IntPtr`. I only accepted this answer cuz its the only one, if you can provider a better one then go for it.

Comment: The first way actually would work but just like `jdweng` said, in the question's comment section, you will have to alloc a array and then assign a pointer, which points to the array, to `IntPtr ProcessIdList`.

I now see that there is no way of having a "automatic"/"dynamic" array(`?`) if you know what i mean...

I guess the other option, in the OP's case, is to not use the struct, and fuctions, all together and just create a `List` which manages the assigned processes.

Comment: jdweng's comment is even more wrong than this answer. I'm afraid to say that he is a serial spreader of false information on pinvoke questions. What you need to do is manual marshaling. Allocate a block of unmanaged memory and manage the offsets yourself. You can use the compiler to calculate the offsets however.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am confused about what that even means... if by manual marshaling you mean that you have to layout every member separately, e.g. `UIntPtr array0 => UIntPtr array1 => UIntPtr array2 => etc.`, then that's a bit odd. Imagine pinvoking a function which outs a struct in which there is a char array, the length of which has to be `32767`, you are telling me that you intend to create a struct with `32767` char fields? Also, sins you said that my second example was also wrong, i wanted to ask you what's the issue with `MarshalAs`, it exists for a reason, doesn't it?

Comment: By manual marshaling I mean that you have to allocate the entire struct dynamically because its size is determined at runtime. And you access members by calculating offsets and using Marshal class to read and write that unmanaged memory. Pinvoke doesn't support variable sized structure marshaling.